# Git Error: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open

Tags: macos, git, libiconv

I was trying to fix up my `.bashrc` on a new mac with some aliases I had and I had made a `.bash_profile` to try to load up the `.bashrc` when the terminal was opened. However, it has been giving me this error every time I try to use a `git` command.

```
git status
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/git
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/git
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I deleted the `.bash_profile` and even reverted back the `.bashrc` but still no good. Any ideas?

Side Note: I have looked at [Git > dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678546/git-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-iconv-open) but his solution doesn't seem to work for me as I have no bash_profile at all now.

Comment: the problem is that SourceTree uses an embedded git instead of system's. [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28032594/576767)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coworker figured it out for my situation.

Create a file `~/.bash_profile` and in it put

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export PATH
```

That seemed to fix it. Seems the issue was with the path.

Comment: on mac, xcode install git at /usr/bin, homebrew or gui install git at /usr/local/bin, and installer from http://git-scm.com/download install git at /usr/local/git/bin. Change PATH is just change which git you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Note, I just answered a similar issue.  Bottom line is there is a broken version of `git` installed on your computer in `/usr/local/git/bin`. Uninstall that one to be certain you won't get this problem.  (I had fixed it on the command line but not in PyCharm -- annoying!)

More specific info in my answer here:

[Git commands not working in Mac terminal: "dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929689/git-clone-command-not-working-in-mac-terminal/37292471#37292471)