# Trouble using GIT with Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

Android studio keeps giving me the error dialog, "No changes detected" when i go to commit my changes to a GIT repository.

When I look in the event log i see this log:

```
com.intellij.openapi.vcs.VcsException: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
           Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
           Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
           dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
           Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
           Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
           during executing git log HEAD --branches --remotes --tags --encoding=UTF-8 --full-history --sparse --max-count=2000 --pretty=format:%x01%H%x02%ct%x02%an%x02%at%x02%ae%x02%cn%x02%ce%x02%P%x02%s%x02%b%x02%B%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 --full-history --sparse --: com.intellij.openapi.vcs.VcsException: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
           Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
           Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
           dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
           Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
           Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
           during executing git log HEAD --branches --remotes --tags --encoding=UTF-8 --full-history --sparse --max-count=2000 --pretty=format:%x01%H%x02%ct%x02%an%x02%at%x02%ae%x02%cn%x02%ce%x02%P%x02%s%x02%b%x02%B%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 --full-history --sparse --
```

Can anyone explain this and/or offer a solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929689/git-clone-command-not-working-in-mac-terminal), you should install **Command line tools** from xCode:

Open xCode and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and click `Downloads`.

Comment: xCode? really? I'll try this, but that blows my mind

Comment: You can also try other answers in the link I provided. Some people solved it by updating their `.bash_profile`

Comment: Yeah saw those answers around updating the .bash_profile but they were greek to me