# Git clone command not working

Tags: macos, git, github, repository, clone

I am new to git and github. I have created my first "HelloWorld" repository on github and I am attempting to clone it onto my mac. I have provided by working directory and the command I tried to use. When I execute the command it will go to a newline and not do anything until I quit out using control C. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
bash-3.2$ pwd

/Users/cameronpattisall/Desktop/Programs/GitHubTest
bash-3.2$ 

bash-3.2$ git clone https://github.com/cameronpattisall/HelloWorld.git

Cloning into 'HelloWorld'...

^C

bash-3.2$
```

Comment: What does it say if you clone verbose? `git clone https://github.com/cameronpattisall/HelloWorld.git --verbose`

Comment: I can clone your repo just fine, how long did you wait before pressing ctrl C?

Comment: Nothing. It just does the exact same thing

Comment: Usually up to about twenty seconds. I'll try again and wait a little longer.

Comment: It shouldn't take that long. Worked for me in about a second

Comment: I just waited a few minutes and nothing every happened

Comment: Is it possible that there is something on my computer that could be blocking my access to github?

Comment: That sounds unlikely but im not sure. Try reinstalling git

Comment: Reinstalled the latest version and I'm having the same problem. Pretty disheartening considering this is my first experience with git haha

Comment: What osx and git versions are you running?

Comment: osx 10.8.5 and git 2.3.5

Comment: actually I just checked and I guess Im still using 1.8.5 even though I just successfully installed 2.3.5

Comment: You might want to remove the 1.8.5 :-)

Comment: I uninstalled the old version and I am now running 2.2.1

Comment: I tried to clone again and have now gotten some weird error messages and then a popup saying that git quit unexpectedly. Ill copy and paste the error messages below

Comment: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: Sounds familiar, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929689/git-clone-command-not-working-in-mac-terminal

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly enough I got it to work fine when I ssh into my university's machines, but there's still something weird going on with my mac. Hopefully I can figure it out!

Comment: Interesting. Let us know how it worked out

Comment: Okay so interestingly enough I found your response to another person having the same issue. I realized I had installed the mavericks version of git so I uninstalled all of git off of my machine and reinstalled the snow leopard version that you provided a link for on sourceforge. I am no longer getting an error message but I am back to my original problem the git clone command simply won't do anything. I am not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/timcharper/git_osx_installer/issues/22 this is the link for the post I was talking about. It seems this fix worked for the RGBboy, but it isn't working for me :/