# What's the meaning of "lazy symbol binding failed" error?

Tags: ios, binding

There are a *lot* of questions on Stack Overflow about specific errors with this phrase, but I wasn't able to find a *general* description of what it is and what causes this type of errors. I just want to get a better understanding of the issue; I suspect that it's covered in depth in some document from Apple, but I wasn't able to find it as well: every google search on the matter results in pages of specific problems and solutions that are tied to specific context. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where and how you get the error? Screen shot? See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455727/git-error-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-iconv-open

Comment: I'm not interested in fixing my particular bug, I'm asking about the error message in general.