# Calling git command from PHP script returns "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed"

Tags: php, git, exec, mamp, dyld

I'm on Mac OSx, using MAMP. When I run git commands directly in the terminal, they work as expected with no errors. But I'm writing a script in php, that is meant to run some git commands, and I am getting the following error:

```
exec('cd /my/path/here/ 2>&1 && git init 2>&1', $out, $return);
```

returns:

`Array
(
    [0] => dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
    [1] =>   Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
    [2] =>   Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    [3] => 
    [4] => dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
    [5] =>   Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
    [6] =>   Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    [7] => 
)`

A search gives a bunch of results ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678546/git-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-iconv-open) for example) explaining how this is an OSx / MAMP issue, with the fix being to add `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/` to your `.bash_profile`. But as I said, I do not have a problem from the terminal, I only get the error when calling git from php's `exec()`. I did add the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` to my `bash_profile`, and it made no difference.

Does calling `exec()` not invoke my `bash_profile`, even if Apache is set to run as my normal user?

Answer (score 0):

If this works, then I would presume exec is not invoking your bash_profile.

```
exec('export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib cd /my/path/here/ 2>&1 && git init 2>&1', $out, $return);
```

Comment: That does work, I actually tried it before posting. But the script I am writing is going to be pushed into my team's version control, and distributed to the other devs. I don't think I can have something that 'non-portable' hard-coded into the script.

Comment: The you likely have a dupe of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428647/php-exec-path-variable-missing-elements

Comment: Thanks for the link. If I run `echo shell_exec("echo $0");` I get `sh`, not `bash`. So it seems PHP isn't even invoking bash. I guess my question becomes how do I get php to use bash when running shell commands, **or** how do I get bourne shell to change its DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH?