# dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open, a conflict between git and postgres

Tags: python, django, git, postgresql

I am trying to get postgres and git to work together in a python3.4 / django1.7 work environment on a Mac with Mavericks. My problem is simple to describe:

When I put the following line in my ./bash_profile, postgres works fine:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib
```

However, when I try something like `git status`, I get the following error (which has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678546/git-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-iconv-open) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455727/git-error-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-iconv-open/19457333#19457333)):

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

When I comment out the line which makes postgres work, git works fine. What do I do to have both work?

I found [a workable answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407995/psycopg2-image-not-found). Yay stackoverflow as usual. I chose to create the symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

try this ?

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I just tried this and no luck. It won't have surprised me if it had though.